# Making an input unselectable

Tags: jquery, html, css

This is kind of weird and I know it seems like this is unnecessary, but in the app we're building it is. Our app is touch screen and we have a section where they have to sign the page. How the signature works is it stores the image data into an input on the page and then grabs it out later.

This is working perfectly, however we of course don't want the input to be shown on the page so the user can mess with it. To fix this I have made it transparent so the user never sees it.

I am worried that they might accidentally click on the field though and decide to be mischievous and mess with it. Is there a way to make it so the user can not select it?

I cannot make it `readonly`, `disabled` or `display:none;`. Readonly stops the validation from working, disabled stops the signature from writing into it and display:none; just removes it from the page.

If any one has any idea's I'm fresh out!

To make it transparent I have this css

```
  background-color: transparent !important;
  border: none !important;
  color: transparent !important;
```

and I have tried `user-select:none;`

Comment: "display:none; just removes it from the page." isn't this what you want?

Comment: Set `display:none` or `visibility: hidden;`

Comment: How about a bored user aware of browser developer tools? You should never rely on a `<form>` to be not manipulated.

Comment: Well ya i guess this has nothing to do with security concern because otherwise, this is not a solution

Comment: @NicoO It's a touch screen, no keyboard or developer tools.

Comment: @LuisP.A., No, I need it on the page or else data cannot be written to it and I can't grab the data from it.

Comment: @A.Wolff, yeah security isn't that big of a deal I just don't want some kid to accidentally click it and then play with it ya know. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this

```
.hideme{
    position:absolute;
    top:-9999px;
    left:-9999px;
}
```

(Assuming **Nic Gutierrez's** answer of `<input type="hidden" value="your image data?">` wont work for you--if it does, his answer is the way to go.)

Comment: Thank you, this seems like this is the best solution for my very weird solution. :)

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried using type="hidden"? ([documentation](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.hidden.html))

Comment: I'm not talking about the "hidden" attribute, I'm talking about the type attribute with "hidden" as value.
<input type="hidden" value="your image data?">

Comment: I can't use the hidden type either unfortunately because the signature needs it to be text for it to write to it.

Comment: In your question you said that you use that input in order to store the image data. Am I right? You can use an input type="hidden" in order to store a string. Hope this make sense.

Comment: It does and normally this would work, but this damn plug in were using to create the signature only writes to inputs with the type of text. I've tried modifying that, but it blew up so I'm hesitant to touch anything they've done (it's a scary place digging in that code!). haha